# Convert non-ASCII chars to Space

Tags: bash, perl, shell, unix

I want to replace all occurrences of non-ASCII chars in Unix to space but group of all the characters should to converted to a single space like :

```
CHAVEZ MONTAï¿½O   should be converted to CHAVEZ MONTAO<followed by one space>
```

How can I do so. I used below Perl command :

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" file.xml
```

But this is converting one single char in one space this is not what I want.

EDIT1:

I know `CHAVEZ MONTAï¿½O`   converted to `CHAVEZ MONTA O` makes more sense. But would be better if it is

```
CHAVEZ MONTAO<followed by one space>
```

But please suggest for `CHAVEZ MONTA O` too.

Comment: i think the output must be `CHAVEZ MONTA O`

Comment: shouldn't it be `CHAVEZ MONTA O`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$ echo 'CHAVEZ MONTAï¿½O' | perl -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]+/ /g'
CHAVEZ MONTA O

$ echo 'CHAVEZ MONTAï¿½O' | perl -pe 's/([^[:ascii:]]+)(.)/\2 /g'
CHAVEZ MONTAO 

$ echo 'CHAVEZ MONTAï¿½O' | perl -pe 's/ï¿½/ /g'
CHAVEZ MONTA O

$ echo 'CHAVEZ MONTAï¿½O' | perl -pe 's/ï¿½([[:ascii:]])/\1 /g'
CHAVEZ MONTAO
```

Comment: Also what if I just want to change ï¿½ to one space ?

Comment: Yep, the above changes to one space . see my update for the second one...

Comment: My question is how can I search for  ï¿½ , just this group of non-ascii chars in unix? Is it possible?

Comment: just directly give that to the search pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
var="CHAVEZ MONTAï¿½O"
echo "${var//+([^[:ascii:]])/ }"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this sed, you can do it like this:

```
sed -s 's/[\d128-\d255]\+/ /' < INPUTFILE
```

It replaces all chars > 128 with one whitespace.